# Call function when other first function finished (callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery 1.8.2 
I have these functions(below), but i want to call the bar() funtion when foo() have finished which dosen't happen. How can i do this?

```
function foo() {
  //something time consuming
  console.log("foo")
}
function bar() {
  console.log("bar");
}
function helloWorld() {
  foo();
  bar();
}
```

Comment: does `foo` has an async task like an ajax request

Comment: in that case see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Js functions by themselves are synchronous,  so the code *as posted* already does what you are asking.   If there's more to it you should include all the details or it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several ways to do this. Right now, I can think of two I regularly use.
The first one (and easiest to understand) is to use callbacks. Simply pass to the first function the second you want to call, as an argument.

```
function foo(callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("foo");
        callback();
    }, 500);
}

function bar() {
    console.log("bar");
}

function helloWorld() {
    foo(bar)
}

helloWorld();
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWNba/109/))

This doesn't require any extra libraries, but when you have a lot of asynchronous stuff, the code quickly becomes a mess.

The other solution, a bit harder to understand but much more powerful, is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Promises are a great way to deal with asynchronous code by offering proper methods to deal with it. The only downside is that you need to learn them, and use an external library.

**EDIT**: As pointed out, I didn't use the JQuery API. Here is how it would looks like using it:

```
function foo() {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("foo");
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 500);
    return deferred.promise();
}

function bar() {
    console.log("bar");
}

function helloWorld() {
  foo().then(bar);
}

helloWorld();
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWNba/113/))

Following example is based on [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

```
function foo() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("foo");
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 500);
    return deferred.promise;
}

function bar() {
    console.log("bar");
}

function helloWorld() {
    foo().then(bar);
}

helloWorld();
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWNba/110/))

Comment: jQuery has its own [Promise API](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) too. It's a horrible API, but at least it wouldn't require any other dependencies

Comment: That's true, thanks for pointing it out. Fortunately, the API seems quite close to Q, so the examples are still understandable.

Comment: Yes it worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

function method1(){
   // some code

}

```
function method2(){
   // some code
}

$.ajax({
   url:method1(),
   success:function(){
   method2();
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a5w2fv69/)**

```
function foo() {
  var deferred=$.Deferred(); //create a deferred object
  console.log("foo");
  return deferred.resolve() //once logging done resolve it and send back
}
function bar() {
  console.log("bar");
}
function helloWorld() {
  $.when(foo()).done(bar()); //you can use $.when and done
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  helloWorld();  
})
```